# call a yes/no form from module in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have module that sends several email automatically. I want to call a userform/msg that asks: "Do you really want to send all the mails?", depending if yes or no is chosen the macro continues or not.

I know the simple solution with MsgBox(text, vbYesNo) but I want to solve this via a userform because I can solve different things with this as well.

how can this be done that the macro only continues when the yes button in the userform has been clicked ? many thanks

Comment: three pieces of code.  One that call the form and a second on the form to call the third if yes.  The third does the work.

Comment: isn't it possible that the main code (the one that calls the form) simply continues after the click in the form has been done?

Comment: See @Joe answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a property to your UserForm that indicates if Yes was clicked, e.g.:

```
Private bYesClicked As Boolean

Public Property Get YesClicked() As Boolean
     YesClicked = bYesClicked
End Property
```

Then set `bYesClicked` to True and hide the UserForm when the Yes button is clicked:

```
Private Sub YesButtonClick()
   bYesClicked = True
   Me.Hide
End Sub
```

To use it, show your UserForm modally, then access the `YesClicked` property:

```
Dim u As MyUserForm
Set u = New MyUserForm
u.Show vbModal
If u.YesClicked Then ...
```

Comment: thank you Joe. just one more thing, when I show the Form modally it does not show on top of all windows, if I do not set to vbModal then the YesClick does not work. Any solution for this (how to show always on top?)?

Comment: @Al_Iskander - not sure about that.  You might try posting a separate question about keeping it a UserForm on top.  Or google shows some techniques using the Windows API, e.g. : https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/386643-userform-always-top.html